# No new leaves on Maples

Tags: trees, leaves, maple

I live in Colorado Springs, CO. My Autumn Fire Maples have not leafed out yet,as of 5/26/21. Anyone else noticed this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a local problem probably

Comment: Have any other trees in your area failed to leaf out? If not and all other trees are in full leaf now, then your tree is probably dead.

Comment: Five in the front are bare, except for just a few shoots. Three in the back are more than half way leafed out.  I just wanted to know if anyone had a similar experience, and what the cause may have been. These maples are all the same, and are at least 25 years old.

Answer (score 1):

We can apply general scientific principles to get more information that will help explain what might have happened. It's just a matter of collecting details that help build the most plausible narrative.

We know the general process for trees to wake from winter dormancy - in particular maples, where in the previous year carbohydrates are stored in the trunk and branches and buds, leaves fall normally leaving healthy scar tissues that prevent the entry of disease. Buds go into the winter fat and ready to burst when the sap rises. A normal winter has no sap rising until spring at which point sap rises through conductive tissues to swell the buds which expand into a normal spring.

So something has interrupted the normal narrative. Check the important points: normal leaf fall? normal scar tissues? wounded branch shows moist tissues? buds fat (slice through one with razor)? snapped twig starts dripping sap? drilled hole in trunk bleeds? sap tastes slightly sweet?

There were some severe cold events during the last winter which resulted in a lot of damage to tender shrubs as far south as Texas. One narrative which might fit, depending on answers to above, is that conductive tissues were damaged by cold. If this is so then the buds might be ready to go but there is insufficient internal pressure to push out the new leaves.